# Send mails async in web.py

Tags: python, email, asynchronous, web.py

I try to solve problem with sending mails(or any long task) in web.py project. What I want is to start sending any mail and return the http response. But this task (sending) is taking a long time. Is there any solution?

Example:

```
import web
''some settings urls, etc.''

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        ''task''
        sending_mail()
        return 'response'
```

I found many examples about async tasks but I think that if this task put to background and return 'response' it will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get away with sending email in a separate thread (you can spawn one when you need to send an email):

```
import threading
threading.Thread(target=sending_email).start()
```

However, the all-around best (and standard) solution would be to use an asynchronous task processor, such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). In your web thread, simply create a new task, and Celery will asynchronously execute it.

---

There is no reason why "returning response" would fail when using a message queue, unless your response depends on the email being sent prior to sending the response (but in that case, you have an architectural problem).

Comment: My response doesn't depend on this task. Ok, thank you so much for clue, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `sending_email()` task to a background queue would be the best solution. This would allow you to return the response immediately and get the results of the `sending_email` task later on.

Let me also suggest taking a look at [RQ](http://python-rq.org/)
It is a lightweight alternative to Celery that I find easier to get up and running. I have used it in the past for sending emails in the background and it didn't disappoint.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it. Now I reading threading module and it seems to be fine. I will make comparison certainly.